# C# check if generic type has attribute by string and assign to it

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

Let's say, I have a class.

```
class A 
{
  string X {get; set;}
  string Y {get; set;}
}
```

and in some method I want to ask, if a generic class (in my case A) has a by string specified argument, and if so, assign to it a value;

```
class CreateGenerics<T> where T:new()
{
  public List<T> create(string attr, string[] attrValues) 
  {
    //I want to check if T has attribute attr (let's say "X")

    List<T> ret = new List<T>();
    foreach(string value in attrValues) {
      T t = new T();
      //set 'attr' attribute of T to value of 'value'
      ret.Add(t);
    }
    return ret;
  }
}
```

Comment: You means properties or [Attribute]?

Comment: I don't know, what you mean.
I want to create
CreateGenerics<A> cg = new CreateGenerics<A>();
and the get created generics like
cg.create("X", ["value1", "value2", ...]);

Comment: @Vlado He's trying to clarify what you mean by "attributes".  In the code you've written, there are no attributes anywhere.  It seems like you really mean that you want to look for properties.  In C# attributes and properties are two totally different things.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you are talking about Properties not Attributes.

You can use reflection and generics for it as you already tried, for example in this case i am checking if property name X exists on the class A:

```
public static List<T> Create<T>(string attr, string[] attrValues) where T: new()
{
   //I want to check if T has attribute attr (let's say "X")

   List<T> ret = new List<T>();
   foreach (string value in attrValues)
   {
      T t = new T();

      foreach (var property in typeof(T).GetProperties())
      {
         if (property.Name == attr) // setting value for x
         {
             property.SetValue(t, value);
         }
      }
       ret.Add(t);
   }
   return ret;
}
```

you can call it like:

```
var result = Create<A>("X",new string[]{"attrValues"});
```

Assuming as you showed your class, all the properties are string

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this for example 
I have created a class called myClassExtensions. I can pass any class object to the class and it will iterate the properties.. so if I want the class to have it's initialized properties changed from `null` to `string.Empty`, I use the static Class creating an Extension Method.. this is very straight forward.

```
public class ClassA 
{
  string X {get; set;}
  string Y {get; set;}
}

 public static class myClassExtensions
 {
    public static void ConvertNullToStringEmpty<T>(this T clsObject) where T : class
    {
        PropertyInfo[] properties = clsObject.GetType().GetProperties();//typeof(T).GetProperties();
        foreach (var info in properties)
        {
            // if a string and null, set to String.Empty
            if (info.PropertyType == typeof(string) && info.GetValue(clsObject, null) == null)
            {
                info.SetValue(clsObject, String.Empty, null);
                // or set some boolean etc since you know the property at this point is of type string
            }
        }
    }
}
```

so I I have a class called `ClassA` I in your example I would do something like this

```
ClassA classaVar = null;
classaVar = (ClassA)FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject(typeof(ClassA));
myClassExtensions.ConvertNullToStringEmpty<ClassA>(classaVar);
```

This will Make the value of `X and Y = string.Empty`

Answer (score -1):

That guy who solved this for me deleted his post (I hope it wasn't me who done it accidently)

[There is fiddle with solution](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NQQsw9):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class A {
    public string X {get; set;}
    public string Y {get; set;}
    public override string ToString() {
        return "X: " + this.X + " Y: " + this.Y;
    }
 }

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<A> list = Create<A>("X", new string[] {"value1", "value2"});
        foreach(A item in list) {
            Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
        }
        list = Create<A>("Y", new string[] {"valueY1", "valueT2"});
        foreach(A item in list) {
            Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
        }
    }
  public static List<T> Create<T>(string attr, string[] attrValues) where T: new()
    {
        //I want to check if T has attribute attr (let's say "X")

        List<T> ret = new List<T>();
        foreach (string value in attrValues)
        {
            T t = new T();


            foreach (var property in typeof(T).GetProperties())
            {
                if (property.Name == attr) // setting value for x
                {
                    property.SetValue(t, "Value");
                }
            }
            ret.Add(t);
        }
        return ret;
    }
}
```

Thank you buddy.

Comment: welcome, you should not be posting answer like this, show code in the post, instead of link to fiddle, if you want to